# How to get value from label in a datagridview C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, datagridview, datagrid

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the value from a label in a datagrid. (Gridview) I'd like to have the value from `<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDAfspraken") %>'></asp:Label>`. I thought I'd be able to say that `int id = Label4.Text` but he doesn't know `Label4`. My question is how do I get this value? I need the primary key to delete rows from my datagrid. Any help is welcome, thanks on advance.

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Width="1000px" HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="IDAfspraken">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDAfspraken") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Afspraak">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Afspraak") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uitleg">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Uitleg") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Categorie">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("IDCategorieën") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Verwijderen">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Verwijder" ForeColor="Red" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);
int index = row.RowIndex;
Label lbltext= (Label)GridView1.Rows[index].FindControl("Label4");
string s= lbltext.Text;
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't recognize the 'HistoryGrid'

Comment: In which event you want to get the label value?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer and for updating. Unfortunately, it doesn't work though, it crashes when I try to delete a record. But I found another method myself, I'll post an answer

Comment: Thanks again for helping

Comment: I'd like to have it on a button_click event

Answer (score 0):

the datagridView contains a property named `DataKeyNames`, the datakeyNames property is set for this purpose, you must set the value of it by passing it to the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working:

```
_controller = new Controller();

        string id="";

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            id = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label4")).Text;

        }

        _controller.VerwijderRecordTblAfspraken(Convert.ToInt32(id));
```